# Facing issue while trying to importing a class from views in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm new to python and django, i'm working on a project and trying to import the classes in views in other file but i'm getting an error as "Import error: No module found".
the folder structures is as follows please help.

```
Travel
   -app
        - settings.py
   -travello
        - views ( its a folder as i have multiple view files)
             - __init__.py
             - views_first.py ( has class First)
             - views_second.py ( has class Second)
   - tests
        - __init__.py
        - test_views.py ( in this file trying to import First and Second class mentioned above)
```

importing First and Second class in test_views.py as below

```
from ml.views.views_first import First
from ml.views.views_second import Second
```

getting "import error" please help

P.S: if u find this question noy worthy before demoting the question, please provide me the answer, it would really help as i'm really struck, thanks in advance

Comment: add full traceback (with your command)

Comment: create __init__.py file in folder.